# Pumping lemma on regular languages?

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I am a bit confused on the theory of the pumping lemma. As I know is used to decide if a language is regular or not.
There is a variable let be m such that is the states?

```
x = vxu
Where vx >= m
And u not ε (>=1)
and a variable i such that v(x^i)u
```

So i cant understand how this is working. I mean where is that useful? By breaking a string into 3 parts and repeat the x?
And how is that showing if it is regular or not?
And is any difference between pumping lemma for regular languages and context-free languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pumping lemma is this:

> For a regular language **L**, there exists a **p > 0** such that for all **w ∈ L**
> where **|w| ≥ p**, there exists some split **w = vxu**, for which the following holds:
>
> - **|vx| ≤ p**
> - **|x| > 0**
> - **vx<sup>i</sup>u ∈ L** for all **i ≥ 0**

The reason I stated it again is because some of your inequalities are wrong.

#### What is the pumping lemma useful for?

The only use of the pumping lemma is in determining whether a language is specifically *not* regular. I.e. if a language does not follow the pumping lemma, it cannot be regular. **But** just because a language pumps, does not mean it is regular (This lemma is used in [Contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrapositive) proofs).

#### How does it show whether it is regular?

As I said above, it doesn't, there are some pumpable languages which are not regular (**EDIT** Wikipedia has an example of a language that satisfies the pumping lemma but is not regular [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true)), however, I think maybe the question you want to ask is this: Why is it that all regular languages can be pumped?

#### Why is it that all regular languages can be pumped?

Consider the characterisation of a regular language, as being recognised by some Discrete Finite Automaton, **M**, with some finite number of states **n**.

Then, consider some string in the language of **M**, which we shall call **w**, for which **|w| ≥ n** holds true.

In checking **w**, **M** must pass through **|w| + 1** states (including its start and end states). So, *by the pigeonhole principle*, **M** must pass through some states more than once (because **|w| + 1 > n**).

Let **w = a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>**

Imagine these are the state transitions of **M**, starting at **q<sub>s</sub>** and ending at **q<sub>f</sub>**, in processing **w**:

```
  a1   a2   a3 ... an
qs → q1 → q2 → ... → qn = qf
```

Now let's look at the section of these state transitions where **M** repeats a state, we'll call that state **R**:

```
  a1   a2   a3     ar      ar+1   ar+2   ar+k       ar+k+1   ar+k+2  an
qs → q1 → q2 → ... → qr = R → qr+1 → ... → qr+k = R → qr+k+1 → ... → qn = qf
```

Let us use a shorthand here to say this:

```
  a1   a2   a3     ar
qs → q1 → q2 → ... → qr
```

is the same as this:

```
   v
qs →* qr
```

where **v = a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>r</sub>**

Now let us split **w** into three parts, **w = vxu**, in the following way:

```
v = a1a2...ar
x = ar+1ar+2...ar+k 
u = ar+k+1ar+k+2...an
```

Now we see that for **v**:

```
   v
qs →* R
```

And for **x**:

```
  x
R →* R
```

And for **u**:

```
  u
R →* qf
```

(All I have done is split up the longer state transition diagram above into three separate ones)

Here you see that **M** will also accept **vu**, **vxxu**, **vxxxu**, ...,  **vx<sup>i</sup>u** for **i ≥ 0**, because processing the string **x** at state **R**, keeps **M** in state **R**.

Essentially, the purpose of the pumping lemma is to find that bit of the string that does not alter the state of **M** when processed.

Now you may wonder. What if there are no strings recognised by **M** for which **|w| ≥ n** holds true?

Well, in that case, you can infer that the language is regular, simply by the fact that it is finite (All finite subsets of ∑* are regular), and furthermore, the pumping lemma is *vacuously* true, you simply choose a pumping length **p > n**, and you can be sure that all strings recognised by **M** that also satisfy **|w| ≥ p** can be pumped (because you know that none exist).

#### Is the pumping lemma for context free languages different?

Yes, here it is:

> For a context-free language **L**, there exists a **p > 0** such that for all **w ∈ L**
> where **|w| ≥ p**, there exists some split **w = uxyzv** for which the following holds:
>
> - **|xyz| ≤ p**
> - **|xz| > 0**
> - **ux<sup>i</sup>yz<sup>i</sup>v ∈ L** for all **i ≥ 0**

The proof for it is a bit more involved, and this answer is already pretty long, so here's the sketch:

Essentially, what this lemma is taking advantage of is another pigeonhole principle style argument, but this time, focusing on the number of variables in the context-free grammar, and the length of its largest production.

Using this information, it's possible to see that for a given grammar, there are some strings large enough that they require a part of the parse tree to be replicated, within itself. This part of the parse tree is **xyz**, and what is happening, is the **y** is being replaced by another **xyz**.

This lemma also can be vacuously true if the language is finite, and is also used in the Contrapositive, like the pumping lemma for regular languages.

If you need more information, I recommend *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by *Michael Sipser*. It has some good sections on both pumping lemmas, and I feel it explains them very well.

Comment: Very nice explanation thank you! I will study your explanation and If any other questions I will post it as comment here. But I think that is accepted answer so I will set it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Just a verification, by saying that a language is not regular, is meant that you can't write a regular expresion for it?

Comment: That's correct, a language is regular if there is a regular expression E that recognises it, or if there is a DFA, M that accepts it (indeed, you can convert any regular expression E into such a DFA M, and vice versa).